# Serving Images from Subdomain Node.js, Apache

Tags: node.js, apache, express, subdomain

I'm currently storing the images in a format like '/imageserving/date/image.png'

When I get an image request it goes to the /imageserving on my backend which returns the image pertaining to the folder. I'm now thinking of introducing a subdomain. My subdomain needs to actually get the request, but how do I route the request to the subdomain?

Currently i have the images going as img src={databaseitem}, where the database item is /imageserving/date/image.png. This populates it with mysite.com/theimage, I need to reroute it to my subdomain so it returns img.mysite.com/theimage

Im currently running my nodejs app on an Apache web server.

How would I go about rerouting the request? Do I have to do it in the backend, or is something I can change on my web server.

Edit: The question was worded poorly
Im basically trying to proxy requests from mysite.com/imageserving/date/xxx to img.mysite.com/date/xxx

```
sendImage: async function(req, res) {

    console.log(req.hostname);


    var filepath = path.join(__dirname, '../../img/uploads/' + req.params.year + '/' + req.params.month + '/' + req.params.id);
    //console.log(filepath);
    res.sendFile(filepath);
}
```

This is obviously sending an image request and going 2 folder back to the subdomain folder, and then getting the filename. I want it not only to get the filename from the subdomain folder, but also send the image from the subdomain itself.

This is my server configuration

```
<Location "/">
<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
    PassengerAppEnv "development"

    PassengerEnabled on
    PassengerBaseURI "/"
    PassengerAppRoot "/home/xxx/mainapp"
    PassengerAppGroupName "xxx - mainappname"
    PassengerRuby /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/libexec/passenger-ruby24
    PassengerPython /usr/bin/python
    PassengerNodejs /opt/cpanel/ea-nodejs10/bin/node
</IfModule>
</Location>
<Directory "/home/xxx/mainapp">
   Allow from all
   Options -MultiViews
   Options -Indexes
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Why proxy them? That seems inefficient. Do you need to wrap authorisation around them or something?

Comment: Well I needed to serve images through the subdomain so when I send the api request to mysite.com/imageserving/date/xxx I would think I need to return the filename from img.mysite.com instead of mysite.com, otherwise it won't send the file from the subdomain. I guess another alternative is to make it hardcode send the filename from subdomain in production, but that seems like a bandaid solution compared to getting Apache configured to just send all /imageserving requests to the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

how did you configure apache and nodejs ?

## 1) node does everything

you can configure apache to route many domains to your nodejs project and let nodejs serve everything. (no need for subdomain, but here it is)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName exemple.com
    ServerAlias img.exemple.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/socket.io [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:10000/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:10000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:10000/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>
```

and then in nodejs

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/imageserving/date/:name", (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.hostname != 'img.exemple.com') return next(new Error('nothing here'))

    res.sendFile('/home/xxx/imageserving/date/'+req.params.name);
});

app.get("/whatever", (req, res) => {
    if (req.hostname != 'exemple.com') return next(new Error('nothing here'))

    res.send('ok');
});
```

now this works :

- curl http://img.exemple.com/imageserving/date/xxx
- curl http://exemple.com/whatever

## 2) or the opposite

tell apache to deal with image serving and nodejs to do processing

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName exemple.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/socket.io [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} transport=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:10000/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:10000/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:10000/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName img.exemple.com
    DocumentRoot /xxx/xxx
</VirtualHost>
```

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();

app.get("/whatever", (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.hostname);
});
```

now this works :

- curl http://img.exemple.com/imageserving/date/xxx
- curl http://exemple.com/whatever

Comment: I havent configured my Apache much outside of changing passenger to let me run server.js instead of app.js. So I have to create a virtual host with the port in the site.conf file? For option 1, you're saying I don't even need a subdomain, I can just have apache recognize img.site.com as the main domain? Also, according to what you've changed in the conf, it will reroute all requestst to the subdomain? What if I only wanted /imageserving api requests to go to the subdomain?

Comment: I can't help much without your current config. Could you paste relevant information in your post ?